# Transform a EditText in to a integer (INT)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-edittext, seekbar

```
        var distanta = findViewById<EditText>(android.R.id.input)
        km = seekBar.progress
        km = km / 60
        km2 = distanta / km
       textView2.setText(km2).toString()
```

Project Link:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s6Pi1kmC1oRmMqf0yJjtV1fAxiDuOr03/view?usp=sharing

Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public inline operator fun BigDecimal.div(other: BigDecimal): BigDecimal defined in kotlin
public inline operator fun BigInteger.div(other: BigInteger): BigInteger defined in kotlin

Comment: textView2.setText(km2.toString()), misplacement of toString

Comment: The problem is :   km = km / 60
               km2 = distanta / km                                 
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public inline operator fun BigDecimal.div(other: BigDecimal): BigDecimal defined in kotlin
public inline operator fun BigInteger.div(other: BigInteger): BigInteger defined in kotlin

Comment: Pretty sure you are looking for getText instead of setText.

Answer (score 1):

Try this that may help you

```kotlin
var distanta = findViewById<EditText>(android.R.id.input)
km = seekBar.progress
km = km / 60
km2 = (distanta.text?.toString()?.toInt() ?: 0) / km
textView2.setText(km2.toString())
```

Comment: yeah you're trying to divide an EditText by a number (you want ``toIntOrNull`` though or you might get an exception)

Comment: @cactustictacs yeah you're right it should be `toIntOrNull()` if the input isn't the right digits.